# How do I get an SVG to work on iOS?

Tags: ios, css, ruby-on-rails, svg

I'm a newbie and I have an SVG that shows in Safari, but fails to show on iOS. I would be grateful for any assistance.

I'm using Rails 4. I have enclosed my code for Application.css, SVG file and index.html.erb.

I've converted the SVG to Base 64 in the hopes that it would help, but it hasn't. Thanks.

```
Application.css 

  #searchbox {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 1% 50%;
  background-size: 14px 13px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}


search2.svg

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="14px" height="13px" viewBox="0 0 14 13" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <title>search_icon</title>
    <description>Created with Sketch (http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch)</description>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
        <text id="" sketch:type="MSTextLayer" font-family="FontAwesome" font-size="14" font-weight="normal" fill="#999999">
            <tspan x="1" y="11"></tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>


index.html.erb

      <%= form_tag companies_path, method: :get do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], placeholder: "Search", id: "searchbox" %>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: Rails is a back-end framework, it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Understood. I just wanted to provide some context and show what I'm doing that's why I've included the index.html.erb code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that there was an issue with my svg file. In the event that this might help someone, I used https://icomoon.io to generate an svg file of the Font Awesome icon I wanted and then used http://b64.io to convert the file to Base64. Background image now shows up on iOS. No issues.